# ASP.NET - .aspx não recebe campos do form post cross domain

Tags: asp.net, formulário, post

Tenho um modelo de form que quero que o cliente use para colar em sua página.

O form aponta para uma página .aspx no meu servidor.

No evento Page_Load na minha .aspx eu quero pegar os campos preenchidos do form via post, no entanto, as quatro opções abaixo retornam array vazio (a primeira) ou nulo (as três seguintes):

```
    var a = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form;
    var b = Request.Form[Constantes.EngageFormParams.EnrollmentKey];
    var c = Request[Constantes.EngageFormParams.EnrollmentKey];
    var d = Request[Constantes.EngageFormParams.Login];
```

Se eu uso method='get' funciona. Como fazer funcionar o post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri o problema.

Páginas .aspx se baseiam no atributo "name" para pegar o valor do campo.

Então:

```
<input type="text" id="meucampo" value="oi"/>
```

Se eu der submit disso e na minha .aspx procurar por:

```
Request["meucampo"]
```

Vai retornar nulo.

No entanto, se eu colocar o atributo name, vai funcionar como esperado para qualquer uma das formas de ler os campos da request que eu coloquei na pergunta.

```
<input type="text" id="meucampo" name="meucampo" value="oi"/>
```